# Compilation of code on build/CI server

Tags: git, github, compilation, continuous-integration

I would like to be able to compile our code base (regardless of how) on the CI/Build server which we have set up, and have it pushed to the repo automatically (so that our main branch can have the updated finished build without each commit being built manually), but am worried about the implication of the CI server having the ability to commit and push to our repository. If for example our CI server is compromised, our code base is then also compromised.

Is there a safe way to have the CI/Build server compile our code and push it to the Repository (our repo happens to be on Github)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably going to have to accept the fact that your build server is susceptible to attack, and can be compromised in the same way your desktop development boxes can be.

But then if you're happy to take this risk on your dev machines, why not on your build server?